# Chrome throwing Network Failure (failed) network error when uploading to S3 and own server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3, networking

I am recording audio with the MediaRecorder API and then uploading those parts to S3 using a multi-part upload. Once every few recordings our user will experience what seems like a faulty part. Chrome throws the following error: Network Failure: NetworkingError [screenshot of the networking error chrome is throwing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJXYp.png).

The status in the networking tab says (failed) and the response is empty. The weird thing about all of this is no matter if I try to upload the part to my own server instead, it still fails. I even tried splitting the part up or changing the destination on S3 but nothing seems to work.

We switched to uploading to Azure and **still** had the problem.

For Azure we have the [following HAR file](https://goldendishes.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fff_redacted.har) generated on my local server. The requests with status code 0 is the one I am talking about.

It is not a CORS issue since it **is** succeeding with all the other parts which makes it even weirder. I let the user disable all extensions (including add blockers and such)

I am completely lost and do not know what to do any more, if anyone could help that would be highly appreciated. Thank you!